# How do you extract a timestamp from a MongoDB ObjectId in Spring Data MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

The MongoDB [documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Optimizing+Object+IDs#OptimizingObjectIDs-Extractinsertiontimesfromidratherthanhavingaseparatetimestampfield.) recommends extracting insertion times from the ObjectId rather than having a separate time field. Does anyone know how to do this with Spring Data MongoDB?

In particular, I'd like to query for documents inserted in a specific date range.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's easy to get times from an `ObjectId`... however you do NOT get ms precision.

`org.bson.types.ObjectId` has 2 methods you can use on it: `getTimeSecond()` and `getTime()` (same as `` `getTimeSecond() * 1000L ``). These will get your a unix timestamp.

I haven't used MongoDB with Spring - but if you can get your hands on the actual `ObjectId` instance its as simple as calling a one of the methods above.

Now - to query for documents in a time range you have to go backwards and create `ObjectId` objects based on a timestamp. Again - this is simple - the `ObjectId` has a constructor can do this for you:

`ObjectId(Date time)`

So - create 2 `ObjectId` instances that represent your min and max time bounds then do a query like:

`db.collection.find({ "field" : { $gt: value1, $lt: value2 } } );`

where `value1` and `value2` represent the `ObjectId` instance you created via `ObjectId(Date time)`

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a *recommendation* there. The doc only says that it's *possible* to get the insertion time from ObjectId. Sorting by _id is also a sorting by insertion time, as mentioned in the docs.

With certain additional effort it is possible to do equality/range queries, but I'd use a separate (indexed) field for that.

Comment: I quote "This page lists some recommendations." "Extract insertion times from _id rather than having a separate timestamp field." I'd forgotten they're called range queries, and thanks to that I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192136/mongodb-range-queries-on-insertion-time-with-id-and-objectid. I'll see if that works.

Comment: @EmersonFarrugia: umm, yeah, this way it could work. Should I delete my answer then? :)

Comment: Nope, but I'd at least edit it. :) It really *is* a recommendation, because the ObjectId gives you a free index on insertion time with a second granularity.

Comment: @EmersonFarrugia: "there's no such thing as a free index", they say :) Queries are harder, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a code snippet for Spring Data that does what I need, thanks to phatduckk's guidance.

```
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria criteria = ...;

    if (startTimestamp != null || endTimestamp != null) {
        criteria = criteria.and("_id");

        if (startTimestamp != null) {
            criteria = criteria.gte(new ObjectId(startTimestamp.toDate()));
        }

        if (endTimestamp != null) {
            criteria = criteria.lt(new ObjectId(endTimestamp.toDate()));
        }
    }

    // use criteria
```

Comment: how can i get timestamp from object id in spring boot ?