# MongoDB get all documents that were created in the last 30 minutes from the _id field alone

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate, nosql

I have a document with no "timeCreated" field.
I would like to get all the entries from the last 30 minutes.
Iv'e heard that the _id field contains the time created logic within it.

How can i do that?

thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you extract a timestamp from a MongoDB ObjectId in Spring Data MongoDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11437513/how-do-you-extract-a-timestamp-from-a-mongodb-objectid-in-spring-data-mongodb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[getTimestamp()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.getTimestamp/#ObjectId.getTimestamp) will give you the date/time from the ObjectId.

You can do the following

```
var oldest = new Date(new Date() - new Date(30 * 60000));
db.collection.find().sort({ _id: -1 }).forEach(function(item) {
  if (item._id.getTimestamp() > oldest){
     ...
  }
});
```

Comment: how can i use the (item._id.getTimestamp() > oldest) to filter the result set?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: myDocument.find(/**where**/ _id.getTime < myDate)

Comment: You can try [$where](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/), but the performance is going to be horrible as it requires a table scan:
`find({ $where: "this._id.getTimestamp() > new Date(new Date() - new Date(30000 * 60000))" })`

Comment: If you can change the code to start recording the creation time in a field, then you can run the code I gave you in the answer and use it to add a 'create_time' field to all existing documents.