# Mongo ObjectId backward conversion from JSON to POJO

Tags: spring, database, mongodb, jackson

in my database I have user with **ObjectId("5f78cd195a52a201fb117175")**.

Then I send it by Spring REST Controller to Angular Frontend and there my object id looks like this:
`{date: 1601752345000, timestamp: 1601752345}` 
Afterwards in frontend I create product object, which contains field userId whose value is set to  `{date: 1601752345000, timestamp: 1601752345}` . That object is sent to backend and later on is saved in db. The problem is that when it is converted by Jackson in Rest controller the userId field has value **ObjectId("5f78cd19065ece5ade441e7a")**.

So from user with ObjectId("5f78cd195a52a201fb117175") I receive ObjectId("5f78cd19065ece5ade441e7a")
I dont have user with this second ObjectId so the field with userId contains no realtion to real user.

DO you know why it happens and how to deal with it ?

Answer (score 1):

`Jackson` treats all objects like `POJO` types. By default, serialises all `getter`-s. Let's assume, that `ObjectId` instance in `Java` is represented by [org.bson.types.ObjectId](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mongodb/bson/latest/org/bson/types/ObjectId.html) which has two `getter`-s:

- [getDate](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mongodb/bson/latest/org/bson/types/ObjectId.html#getDate()) in your case `date` field in `JSON`
- [getTimestamp](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mongodb/bson/latest/org/bson/types/ObjectId.html#getTimestamp()) in your case `timestamp` field in `JSON`

These two fields will be serialised to `JSON` payload. Deserialisation process needs constructor and setters. I guess, in this case constructor [ObjectId​(int timestamp, int counter)](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mongodb/bson/latest/org/bson/types/ObjectId.html#%3Cinit%3E(int,int)) will be chosen (but I am not sure). You can try to create new instance of `ObjectId` using this constructor with values from your `JSON` payload.

When you use `Jackson` to serialise/deserialise types from 3-rd party libraries you can expect that there is a module implemented for this. Take a look on [MongoJack](https://github.com/mongojack/mongojack):

> Since MongoDB uses BSON, a binary form of JSON, to store its
> documents, a JSON mapper is a perfect mechanism for mapping Java
> objects to MongoDB documents. And the best Java JSON mapper is
> Jackson. ...

You need to register this module and serialisation/deserialisation processes should work as expected.

See also:

- [How do you extract a timestamp from a MongoDB ObjectId in Spring Data MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11437513/how-do-you-extract-a-timestamp-from-a-mongodb-objectid-in-spring-data-mongodb)
- [Binary JSON with bson4jackson](https://michelkraemer.com/binary-json-with-bson4jackson/)